# Bitcode bundle could not be generated (while archiving) because Static Framework (.framework) was built without full bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, ios-frameworks, bitcode

We are trying to enable Bitcode fully in our Static Framework but we are receiving the following error while archiving the app when the framework is integrated with it though we are able to build it on the simulator or device.

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '.framework/p-iOS(PTFWOperationPrepareTransaction.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '.framework/p-iOS' for architecture armv7
```

We have verified Bitcode state through `otool -l Versions/A/p-iOS  | grep __bitcode` and seems like it is enabled correctly
[image].

Following are our project settings for **bitcode** on framework's end,
[image]

And following are our project settings for **bitcode** on app's end,
[image]

**A humble request:**
Please review our settings in the above screenshots as we have already checked all the related queries on SO so please **do not** give them as a reference.
[image]

Also, we have already tried [Static Libraries, Frameworks, and Bitcode](https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9) to get our things fixed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any update on this? @ihammys

Comment: Also struggling with this... Did you solved it? I have created another issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082111/compiled-framework-provides-bitcode-error-when-archiving

Comment: any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 11):

I also had this problem with a framework I built.
This is what worked for me:

1. In *Build Settings* of the framework **project** set `Other C Flags` to `-fembed-bitcode`
2. In the *Build Settings* of the framework **target** add a user defined flag called `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE` with the value of `bitcode`
3. Both in the framework project and target, `Enable Bitcode` should be set on `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been bothering me for a long time and like you I did everything I could and it still didn't work. Finally I found out it was a stupid configuration I made in `Podfile`:

```
target 'MySDK' do
  project 'Src/MySDK.xcodeproj'
end
target 'Demo' do
  project 'Demo/Demo.xcodeproj'

  pod 'MySDK', :path => $spec_path
end
```

Since my SDK doesn't have any dependencies, I added such a target to automatically add my SDK project to the workspace created by cocoapods.

As a result, even though this target doesn't have any dependencies, this action creates `libPods-MySDK.a` in my SDK and adds it in `Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries`.

This causes the same problem as yours.

The solution is simple, delete the empty targets in the podfiles, delete the invalid `Pods` and `Frameworks` directories, and delete the pod-related config in `Build Phases`.