# Build a fat framework in xcode11 with full bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode11, bitcode

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to build a cocoapods framework in xcode11 and then use it in an iOS SDK.

**What I have tried:**

- Set `Enable Bitcode` to yes
- Before building the framework, I have set `Other C flags` to `-fembed-bitcode` and `-fembed-bitcode-marker` respectively for release and debug.
- I have also set user defined build setting to `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE` as `bitcode` and `marker`.
- Build for both simulator and device; setting build scheme to release.
- Follow [this](https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/a-noobs-guide-to-creating-a-fat-library-for-ios-bafe8452b84b) article to build a fat framework using lipo.

**What issue I am facing:**

After releasing the pre-release version of the framework to Cocoapods, I install it in my SDK. The build for SDK fails for device(release) with the following message:

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/sourobratasarkar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Beaconstac-dpnhqvwchyqaeyavlbmfsntqlgnn/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/EddystoneScanner/EddystoneScanner.framework/EddystoneScanner' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/sourobratasarkar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Beaconstac-dpnhqvwchyqaeyavlbmfsntqlgnn/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/EddystoneScanner/EddystoneScanner.framework/EddystoneScanner' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It says the framework was built without full bitcode for architecture arm7.

*Is there anything I am missing while building the framework? Using `lipo -info` I can see that arm7 architecture is present.*

PS: The build succeeds for debug (both device and simulator) and release (simulator).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... A solution would be great...

Comment: @davidOhara I found my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082111/compiled-framework-provides-bitcode-error-when-archiving

Comment: So you also managed to have a fat library, including simulator arch with bitcode enabled which is also able to be uploaded to the store?

Comment: I was able to add the fat framework to an SDK and use that in an app. I was able to archive the app. They was no build failures in simulator/device for both release and debug.

Comment: Ok, but its not possible to upload the app to the store, right?! I mean with Bitcode enabled and having also simulator arch inside it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there was no issue in the way I built the framework. Adding the following to the Podfile of the SDK where I was using the framework resolved this for me:

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE'] = 'bitcode'
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```