# Binary iOS framework archive error: bitcode bundle could not be generated because framework was built without full bitcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have created a binary iOS framework (framework with source obfuscated), and after jumping through hoops to get it to run, it gives an error on archive

bitcode bundle could not be generated because framework was built without full bitcode

bitcode bundle could not be generated because framework was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file -framework path- for architecture arm64

I set validate workspace to YES, and set the framework to sign & embed

I tried setting enable bitcode to NO and YES,

I tried setting skip install to YES and NO

I tried setting enable bitcode to yes and no, and I tried what this comment suggested:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265097/15266127

And I still have the same error. It's actually driving me insane.

This feels like I'm working through some dystopian level bureaucracy. Help me out here I'm suffering.